# Using csvkit to sort on multiple columns, reverse order for some

Tags: csvkit

I am using `csvsort` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) to sort my csv data. I'd like to sort based on two columns, one of which should be in reverse order. Is that possible?

For example:

```
echo 'v1,v2,v3
      a,1,z
      b,3,x
      c,2,y
      a,2,y
      b,1,x
      c,3,z' | csvsort -c1,2 |csvlook
```

gives

```
| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| -- | -- | -- |
| a  |  1 | z  |
| a  |  2 | y  |
| b  |  1 | x  |
| b  |  3 | x  |
| c  |  2 | y  |
| c  |  3 | z  |,
```

but I want

```
| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| -- | -- | -- |
| a  |  2 | z  |
| a  |  1 | y  |
| b  |  3 | x  |
| b  |  1 | x  |
| c  |  3 | y  |
| c  |  2 | z  |.
```

`csvsort -r -c1,2` reverses order on both columns. `csvsort -rc 1 -c 2` sorts only on column 2 (in reverse, so the same as `csvsort -rc 2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way with csvkit is

```
csvsql --query "select * from input order by v1, v2 desc" input.csv
```

it gives you

```
v1 v2 v3
a  2  y
a  1  z
b  3  x
b  1  x
c  3  z
c  2  y
```